# D3 Interactive Legend on Multi Line Chart Issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been asked to add an interactive legend to my Multi-line chart. My Multi-line chart has a nest with two keys and it made things difficult for my legend. Here's an old [EAMPLE](http://www.d3noob.org/2014/07/d3js-multi-line-graph-with-automatic.html) I'm using for adding an interactive legend.

**My issues:**

1) I'm trying to display the top level key for the legend so that it shows *system01, system02, system03* and so on instead of displaying the two keys together. For example, `system01 0` and `systmem01 2` become `system01` so when it is clicked it will hide both lines.

2) After making the lines inactive, the tooltip still displays when mousing over the chart.

Here's my [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/clarkus978/v6yabs4c/18/)

**Snippet for adding the Legend:**

```
var chartBody = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "chartbody")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

for (var key in storages) {
    if (storages.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log("key:", key, [storages[key]]);
        var capSeries = d3.line()
            .x(function(d) {
                return x(d.date); })
            .y(function(d) {
                return y(d.availableVolumeCapacity); })
            .curve(d3.curveCardinal);
        // mapping of data to line using the capSeries function
        chartBody.append("path")
            .data([storages[key]])
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("id", 'tag'+ key.replace(/\s+/g, ''))
            .attr("d", capSeries)
            .style("stroke", z(key));
    }
}

// spacing for the legend
legendSpace = width/nest.length;

// Loop through each symbol / key
nest.forEach(function(d,i) {

// Add the Legend
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", (legendSpace/2)+i*legendSpace)  // space legend
        .attr("y", height + (margin.bottom/2)+ 5)
        .attr("class", "legend")    // style the legend
        .style("fill", function() { // Add the colours dynamically
            return d.z = z(d.key); })
        .on("click", function(){
            // Determine if current line is visible
            var active = d.active ? false : true,
            newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
            // Hide or show the elements based on the ID
            d3.select("#tag"+d.key.replace(/\s+/g, ''))
                .transition().duration(100)
                .style("opacity", newOpacity);
            // Update whether or not the elements are active
            d.active = active;
            })
        .text(d.key);

});
```

Comment: I've solved your issue no2, didn't understand issue no 1, well see this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/v6yabs4c/20/)

Comment: I apologize for not explaining myself clearly. I'm looking to group the subkeys for the legend. For example `system01 0` and `systmem01 2` become `system01` so when it is clicked it will hide both lines.

Comment: @Clarkus978 you can just change the displayed text and it will work fine, take a look at my answer

Comment: @mkaran thank you for your answer, but that doesn't solve the issue. I'm looking to group `system01 0` and `system01 02` so that it only displays a single `system01` in the legend. When `system01` is clicked on it will hide lines `system01 0` and `system01 2`.

Comment: @Clarkus978 oh, I see! thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/mkwne5uh/

For 2) 
A simple solution would be to keep track of the hidden and apply mouseover and mouseout conditionally.

```
// define an array to hold the hidden info
var hidden = [];
...
...
 // Loop through each symbol / key
    nest.forEach(function(d,i) {

    // Add the Legend
        svg.append("text")
            .attr("x", (legendSpace/2)+i*legendSpace)  // space legend
            .attr("y", height + (margin.bottom/2)+ 5)
            .attr("class", "legend")    // style the legend
            .style("fill", function() { // Add the colours dynamically
                return d.z = z(d.key); })
            .on("click", function(){

                // Update whether or not the elements are active
                // initial d.active will be undefined, so on first click
                // d.active will become false like this
                d.active = !d.active;  
                // Determine if current line is visible
                newOpacity = d.active ? 0 : 1;

                // if category is not active now, remove it
                if(!d.active){
                    hidden.splice(hidden.indexOf(d.key), 1);
                }
                else{// keep it for use later on
                    hidden.push(d.key)
                }
                // Hide or show the elements based on the ID
                d3.select("#tag"+d.key.replace(/\s+/g, ''))
                    .transition().duration(100)
                    .style("opacity", newOpacity);
                })
            .text(d.key);
    });
```

and then:

```
function mouseover(d) {
    if( hidden.indexOf(d.data.storageSystem + " " + d.data.poolId)> -1) return;
....
function mouseout(d) {
        if( hidden.indexOf(d.data.storageSystem + " " + d.data.poolId)> -1) return;
```

As for 1) you could use `.text(d.key.split(" ")[0])` but I am not so sure it would be the best solution.

Hope this helps, good luck!